# Loop through records and generate time stamp

Tags: sql, loops, crystal-reports

My report tracks all high level incidents. As part of the report I want to be able to pull through if an hourly chase has been taken on the incident. The update would be stored in a table called ActionTBL in a field called `Action_Type` and incident is stored in the `IncidentTBL`.

I want to be able to loop through the field `Action_Type` and pull out all the actions which equal "Chase" - then record the time when the action was taken. The report would be something like:

```
Chase 1: 12:00
Chase 2: 13:00
Chase 3: 15:00
```

The report would then highlight that Chase 3 was taken an hour later than it should have been. How can I do this in Crystal Reports, if I even can?

Comment: Is the "time the action was taken" a field in your report? Or is that generated based on when you *run* the report?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify this, this is recorded in a field called date_actioned.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give you the best advice since we don't know what your report looks like, or how it's structured. Since we don't know that, the most likely answer is to use a Subreport. This should work without you having to restructure your report.

You'll want to place the subreport in your report footer, and suppress the Headers and Footers inside said subreport.

Assuming you've already linked up your tables correctly, all you would have to do is reuse your original record selection formula to have an additional clause where `Action_Type = "Chase"` and group by `date_actioned`. Reuse the same parameters as your parent report and pass them in. This should generate the list you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you look only for the records with chase then the solution that I would think of is to use `Record Selection Formula` to retrive only records with `chase`

Go to `Report --> Select Expert --> Record` and write below code:

```
Action_Type= "Chase"
```

This will omit all other records and retrive only records with Chase and place the Action_Type in details and then use field that has time stored